# Dynamic Field Validation Progress-4GL

Tags: validation, dynamic, field, progress-4gl

Created a process that links enterprise data from XML file in to a PROGRESS 4GL Database ... using dynamic Queries, I pass the Table Name, Field Name and it's Value into an include which currently uses a temp-table copy of the table I am populating ... what I was hoping not to have to do is write specific validation clauses for each field being populated ... the expectation was that the Schema Validation clause would kick in when the field was being written ... what I expect I might have to do now is get the validation clauses from the actual table field, build a runtime program to do the validation. hndField:Validation-Expression and hndField:Validation-Message ... kind of defeats the purpose of having the Dynamic Query if I have to build a runtime validation program for each field.

Concepts that are causing me grief:

using: DEFINE TEMP-TABLE Blah LIKE Foo.

1) Doesn't appear to include Foo Validation Clauses on Fields in Blah (confirmed viewing hndField:Validate-Expression ... always returns ? for temp-table fields) Even if I assign the Foo Validation and Message to the Temp-table field, doing an update Blah.somefield is not validated.

2) using a Dynamic Query with;
Assign hndField:Buffer-Value = "somevalue" no-error.
even if I query using Foo instead of Blah, the assignment doesn't use the SCHEMA field Validation Clause ... even added a VALIDATE Foo no-error.

3) A buffer-copy Blah to Foo also doesn't appear to do any validations

How else can force Schema Validation to keep this data linking purely dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Have you simply tried adding the 'VALIDATE' option?

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE Blah LIKE Foo VALIDATE.
```

That will work as good (or bad) as normal validation.

From the online help:

> VALIDATE
>
> The temp-table fields inherit, from the dictionary, validation expressions and validation messages from the database table, table-name.

Personally I prefer to keep validation in the code and out of the database. At least except for the most basic validation (perhaps making sure that there's a master record for a detail record).

I find the dictionary approach limited and hard to maintain. But I guess that's just opinion based.

Comment: I agree.  Dictionary validation is awful.  It "makes a good demo" (back in 1985...) but is otherwise a bad approach.